# I can't manipulate an uploaded image with GD

Tags: php, jquery, image, get, gd

I'm trying to allow users to upload an image with any height/width and then display that image on my page cropped to a 400-by-400 square. The way I'm attempting to do that is by taking the URL of the uploaded image, send it to my PHP script via GET and then add a new img tag to the DOM containing the resized image.

The trouble I'm encountering is that the cropped image is always black, even when using imagecopyresampled(). Here's a live [example](http://andrewtgibsongraphics.com/upload_test/).

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1'>

        <title>Test</title>

        <!-- styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet"    href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

        <!-- scripts -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src='js/script.js'></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <label for='existing'>Choose existing photo:</label>
            <input id="existing" type="file" accept="image/*">


        <div id="photo_container">
            <img id="photo" src="" width="640" height="480">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

MY JS:

```
    $(document).ready(
    function()
    {   
        var showPicture = document.querySelector("#photo");
        var takePicture = document.querySelector("#existing");

        takePicture.onchange = function( event )
        {
            var files = event.target.files, file;

            if (files && files.length > 0) 
            {
                file = files[0];
            }

            try 
            {
                var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                var imgURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

                showPicture.src = imgURL;

                $('#photo_container').append('<img id="photo_new" src="http://andrewtgibsongraphics.com/upload_test/crop.php?source='+imgURL+'"/>');

            }

            catch(e) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    var fileReader = new FileReader();

                    fileReader.onload = function (event) 
                    {

                        showPicture.src = event.target.result;

                        $('#photo_container').append('<img id="photo_new" src="http://andrewtgibsongraphics.com/upload_test/crop.php?source='+imgURL+'"/>');
                    };

                    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }

                catch(e) 
                {

                    var error = document.querySelector("#error");

                    if (error) 
                    {
                        error.innerHTML = "Neither createObjectURL or FileReader are supported";
                    }
                }
            }
        }; 
    });
```

MY PHP:

```
    $source = $_GET['source'];

    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($source);

    $myImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor(400,400);

    imagecopyresampled($newImage, $myImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, 400, 400, $width, $height);

    imagejpeg($newImage);

    imagedestroy($newImage);
    imagedestroy($myImage);
```

Comment: The URL being passed to PHP is a `blob` URL only valid within the Javascript. PHP has no idea what to do with it. You need to upload the whole image to the server to make this work. In any case, you could do this all in Javascript unless you need to upload the image for some other reason. Look at the Canvas element.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I modified the code so that it now takes the uploaded image and attempts to place the image on a canvas with half the width and height. Then, I convert that canvas to a URL and assign it as the src of a different image element. Still, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`URL.createObjectURL` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.createObjectURL) creates a temporary URL for use within the browser, for a file which hasn't actually been uploaded yet. Consequently, this URL will be completely meaningless to the PHP code running on a remote server.

MDN has [a quite thorough tutorial of the API you are using here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications), discussing both how to display images before they are uploaded, and how to upload them asynchronously.